# Pen drive disconnects rapidly and cyclically

Tags: backup, usb-flash-drive

I have old Transcend 4GB pen drive, which shows as connected for only several seconds, disconnects and starts to reconnect. I am able to execute 'dir', 'tree' and start copying files which ends in seconds. The issue occurs in cyclic manner disregarding operations performed.

I use Windows 10, 64 bit version, have already crossed out the power support (found the idea that the power saving option makes this issue, so 'USB selective suspend setting' is disabled), have tried to update drivers, but these are up-to-date.
Also, the software provided by the [manufacturer](https://www.transcend-info.com/Support/Software-1) or [repair tool](https://www.transcend-info.com/supports/special.aspx?no=3) doesn't work - it has no chance to recognize pendrive when it disconnects. This renders software useless as it returns error in finding the proper device. In the computer I use USB 2.0, the file system is FAT32.

The 'chkdsk H: /r /x' command crashes at 0% after disconnect.

Is there any way to keep it connected or at least ackup the files disregarding rapid disconnections?

Comment: Have you tried a different computer? If it doesn’t work there, then you’re out of luck. If it does work, copy the data. Contact a data recovery company if you have a bad USB drive.

Comment: @appleoddity - actually, as the drive is recognised for a short time ddrescue can probably (possibly with multiple tried) do a bitcopy of the data which can be read, to allow DIY recovery.

Comment: Yes, I have tried more computers, with various OS (works the same). @davidgo it seems like a good answer (if nothing else seems possible, it is the best available, probably will do it).

Comment: @davidgo ddrescue at FreeBSD works like a charm. xcopy under Win 10 with /E /C /d /Z run in loop almost keep up (handles all files up to about 6MB), maybe you would like to answer?